# addClass and removeClass previous class on keydown Jquery

Tags: jquery, carousel, addclass, keydown, removeclass

I'm trying to work out how to change the class on an image on a keydown function. Basically when I press the right arrow key I want the carousel to move to the right, for the image to change class to 'selected' and to remove the class from the previous image. I'd like the same to happen with the left arrow key. I currently have the moving right and left on keydown working fine, but I'm struggling with adding and removing the class. This is my current html —

```
<body>    
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="perspective">
        <div id="carousel">
            <figure>
                <img src="image1.png" class="selected">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="captionHeading">
                        <h2 style="captionHeading">Title</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p2>Some Text</p2>
                    <p3>Some Text</p3>
                </div>
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="image2.png">
                <div class="caption">
                    <div class="captionHeading">
                        <h2 style="captionHeading">Title</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p2>Some Text</p2>
                    <p3>Some Text</p3>
                </div>
            </figure>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the code to animate the carousel right and left —

```
    $("body").keydown(function(e) {

        if (e.which == 39) { // right
            console.log(e.which);
            rotate_int -= 1;
            animate_slider();
        } else if (e.which == 37) { // left
            console.log(e.which)
            rotate_int += 1;
            animate_slider();
        }
    });
```

Any help would be great. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that rotate_int is the index of the current carousel then your code would be:

```
var slides = $('#carousel').find('figure > img');
$("body").keydown(function(e) {

    if (e.which == 39) { // right
        console.log(e.which);
        slides.eq( rotate_int ).removeClass( 'selected' );
        rotate_int -= 1;
        slides.eq( rotate_int ).addClass( 'selected' );
        animate_slider();
    } else if (e.which == 37) { // left
        console.log(e.which)
        slides.eq( rotate_int ).removeClass( 'selected' );
        rotate_int += 1;
        slides.eq( rotate_int ).addClass( 'selected' );
        animate_slider();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/s0h28mop/7/)

Based on the demo here is the updated code:

```
    var slides = $('#carousel').find('figure > img');
    $("body").keydown(function (e) {

        var index = slides.index( slides.filter('.selected') );
        if (e.which == 39) { // right
            console.log(e.which);
            index = (index + 1) % slides.length;
            slides.removeClass('selected');
            slides.eq(index).addClass('selected');
            rotate_int -= 1;                
            animate_slider();
        } else if (e.which == 37) { // left
            console.log(e.which);
            index = index === 0 ? slides.index - 1 : index - 1;
            slides.removeClass('selected');
            slides.eq(index).addClass('selected');
            rotate_int += 1;
            animate_slider();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ahh I think that's so close but it still doesn't work. Here's a link to the original script (unedited by me). I've replaced the script between lines 46 and 54.
[link](https://github.com/dcoulter45/3d_carousel/blob/master/js/3dcarousel.js)

Comment: How about creating a jsfiddle of what you have so far? That might be more helpful.

Comment: Hi @PeterKA here is a jsfiddle of what I've got minus all the other parts to the website which aren't relevant to this. It doesn't seem to work at all in the fiddle for some reason — http://jsfiddle.net/s0h28mop/

Comment: Any way you can get the fiddle to work? In the meantime I have changed the code slightly ... see the var slides = ... line.

Comment: Hi @PeterKA just working on the jsfiddle now. The code change didn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @PeterKA one thing I have just noticed however on my version on my computer is that when I press the right arrow, the carousel moves to the right (as it should), but the class is applied as if the carousel has moved to the left if that makes sense? I still haven't had any luck with the jsfiddle yet. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the update; without a working jsfiddle all I can do is guesswork :/ ... How about if you switch the `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` lines in both the `then` and `else` clauses?

Comment: Hi @PeterKA that didn't work either unfortunately, but here's the finally working fiddle — http://jsfiddle.net/s0h28mop/6/